# Why Some Assembly Instruction Are not Documented

Tags: delphi, assembly, inline-assembly, x86-16

There are some Assembly instruction in Delphi Source Codes which I cannot found anywhere in Assembly Cheat Sheets including:

1. fld
2. fabs
3. fcompp
4. fstsw

I read these assembly instructions in "Power" function; But I cannot found them in [this](http://www.jegerlehner.ch/intel/IntelCodeTable.pdf) cheat sheet or similar cheat sheets.

Does these instructions are not belong to 8086, 8088 CPU instructions? or Simply these instructions are not included in these Cheat Sheets?

Is there a good Web Page which list all Assembly instructions?

Comment: They are x87 floatingpoint instructions.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

These are all floating point instructions, which (primarily for historical reasons) are often documented separately from integer instructions. For a more authoritative reference, consider looking at the Intel [manual](http://www3.intel.com/Assets/PDF/manual/253666.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

These seem to be floating point instructions. In the old times, a separate chip implemented these (8087), so lists of instructions as the one you link avoided those operations. Anyway, you can find them in any more recent assembly manual, because floating point instructions were inserted into the same chip long ago. Look at [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_instruction_listings), for example.

Comment: It was the 486DX to ship first with an integrated FPU. 8086, 80286 and 80386 all shipped with a socket to host an 8087, 80287 and 80387 "math coprocessor". 486SX were 486DX with the FPU absent or disabled. The 487 was a full blown 486DX that when installed disabled the 486SX - actually one owned a biprocessor machine but one of the chips was disabled... since the Pentium all PCs came with a FPU. If the math coprocessor is missing, the CPU can emit an interrupt if a FPU instruction is encountered, giving the application or OS a chance to emulate it.

Answer (score 1):

Never mind. I found the list of All 8086 Assembly instructions here:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_instruction_listings

Comment: Please do not use Wikipedia as an official reference. The canonical reference in this case is: http://www.intel.com/design/pentiumii/manuals/243191.htm

Comment: @Jim Brisson: The link you've provided is to a ~12 year old version of the manual. While you can argue that it's still relevant (F.P. instructions haven't changed much) I think the current version of the same manual is generally a better choice (see link in my answer).

Comment: Indeed it is, and I am ready to say that I procured this by a careless search for "intel instruction set manual". I will even go as far as saying that I pondered the /pentiumii/ contained in the link after posting it here, sharing the same thought as you. Alas, I was content with the fact that indeed those instructions in question haven't undergone major changes...rest assured, I do not fail see the (albeit minor) irony of ranting about canonical references, though.

Comment: Given the processors the Delphi compiler supports I believe that link could have been ok... <g> Although it is true BASM probably supports instructions the compiler itself doesn't use.